# How can I use POST method in place of GET method

Tags: java, string, rest, spring-boot, get

I used POST method but getting following error. Last line shows the error. Initially , I didn't use SecurityConfiguration. Right now, I am using SecurityConfiguration to permit all and still getting authentication error.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

[2020-02-19 16:02:59.357] [DEBUG] [Context:FilterSecurityInterceptor] [] [Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@64bc4ef4: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 53EB7CECE3D38AF3B70968DB6125DA86; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS]
[2020-02-19 16:02:59.368] [DEBUG] [Context:AffirmativeBased] [] [Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1173b3b2, returned: -1]
[2020-02-19 16:02:59.371] [DEBUG] [Context:ExceptionTranslationFilter] [] [Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point]
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-02-19 16:02:59.385] [DEBUG] [Context:AndRequestMatcher] [] [Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]]
**[2020-02-19 16:02:59.386] [DEBUG] [Context:AntPathRequestMatcher] [] [Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /**']**

```
   @PostMapping(value ="/createAncillaries")
   public CreateOrderResponseType createAncillaries(@RequestBody(required=true) String message ) {
      return orderDetailsService.createAncillaries(message);
   }
```

Comment: did you try using httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll();

Comment: I tried and got same error.

Comment: If you check this line: "[Context:AntPathRequestMatcher] [] [Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /']**" it seems to be forwarding the request to /error page. Did you check the issue here. You might want to use "/*" instead of "/" in antMatchers

Comment: I think it worked as I am not getting authentication error. It moved to the service layer . Right now, I don't have test data. So, unable to test completely. Thanks Lalit.

Answer (score 1):

URLs have length restrictions. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/919158.

Try using POST method and post the data as `@RequestBody`

Comment: I tried to use POST method with @RequestBody but I am getting spring security authentication error even though I have same authentication  spring:
 security:
  user:
   name: XXX
   password: YYY

Comment: I updated the post and it is giving authentication error because of POST method as it is expecting GET method

Comment: Authentication is giving trouble, not the post method which you have already correct. Access denied error and this route /error is causing issue. Is the error routing uses wrong Http method? Check your antMatchers.

Comment: I have same authentication for GET and POST , also throughout the project. It is working for GET .  Just this POST transaction is not working. I have other POST transactions which are meant to be POST and is working fine.

Comment: I got the String of message from Find method - step 1 , then passing the message in createOrder - Step 2.  Now I merge both the method , so there is no problem of message passing.

Comment: I am now trying to use POST method so that I can reuse the code for multiple calls.